# Webpack css/style loader unresponsive for classes and ids

Tags: css, webpack

I have been trying to learn webpack. I'm running into issues with loading CSS as modules. When I use a css page, the program has no problem reading the tags, but for some reason will not read the classes or ids. ie -

```
body {
 color: red; //works
}

.row {
 background-color: green; //does not work
}
```

My loaders are setup like this:

```
{
  test: /\.css/,
  loader: 'style-loader'
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}
```

And my import looks like this:

```
import styles from './css/main.css';
```

I am also working with react jsx files, if that makes any difference. My jsx looks like this:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="eight columns">
      <DOMviewer />
    </div>
    <div className='four columns'>
      <Editor />
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I get the loaders to read the ids and classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the string "row" as a string, use it as property on the `styles` object, because the actual class name will be created by the loader, and will include a random hash because of this definition (this creates the module's namespace):

```
'[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
```

For example, to use "class" row:

```
<div className={ styles.row }>
```

Comment: You're the best! Thanks so much. I will checkmark this as soon as it will let me.

Comment: You're welcome. Also look at [react CSS modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules), which makes it easier to use.